# Nodejs module not found

Tags: node.js, terminal, pm2

I'm trying to install socket.io on localhost.

I installed nodejs like this:

```
1. npm install pm2 -g
2. npm install socket.io
3. pm2 start C:\xampp\htdocs\server\app.js
```

Yesterday It was successful and I worked on my project.

But today when I start same file again, I get an error like this;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDE2p.png

And I open logs, the message showed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F358O.png

I'm trying to solve this problem for hours.

I even tried to reinstall Node at least 4-5 times.

Still same problem, please help.

Comment: Did you try to `npm install` your packages before launch pm2 ?

Comment: Yes, btw I solved the issue, it's because I called socket.io from wrong folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance I would recommend you to run a `npm install` before starting your app.

We need additional information about your `require` statement, your package.json dependencies and the full error message.

Comment: Which package.json file? There is many folders in the socket.io module and many package.json files.

Comment: The package.json from your app, in your case it should be C:\xampp\htdocs\server\package.json. Have you tried the `npm install` followed by a pm2 reload?

Comment: Yes, I did required installations but there is not any package.json in that folder. There is only app.js file; https://i.imgur.com/3vDj13U.png

Comment: There is no node_modules subfolder in your project folder? The node_modules folder is where your project dependencies live. The `npm install socket.io` command creates it.

It is also a good practice to have a package.json file in your project in order to state your dependencies. You can read more [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file)

Comment: Thank you very much. I spend my 3 hours for this :))